# Concurrently Running VirtualBox and Docker on Linux Host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, docker

I have an Ubuntu server already running VirtualBox, and I want to run Docker containers from it as well. Both containerization/virtualization frameworks on the same physical box. Is this a no-no? Are there any limitations to this approach, or potential landmines to watch out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no problem with a hypervisor and Docker running simultaneously on the same Linux OS. They have basically nothing in common.

On Windows or macOS it would be a different story because you need a Linux kernel for Docker and it would have to run in a VM. There are some caveats with such setups.

Exceptions: Windows-native containers on Windows Server and WASM containers.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't think there would be a problem, but I'm no sysadmin so it doesn't hurt to double-check